# "Illegal argument to function" in Postgres when doing select on a view with pgp_sym_decrypt() expression

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, typeorm

I am using pg_sym_decrypt/encrypt to decrypt/encrypt some of the fields in my table. Decryption happens on select in a separate EntityComputed view that has a one-to-one relationship with the Entity that stores the encrypted fields.

I get this error when doing a select over my data:

```
"driverError":{
  "length":92,
  "name":"error",
  "severity":"ERROR",
  "code":"39000",
  "file":"pgp-pgsql.c",
  "line":"610",
  "routine":"decrypt_internal"
},
```

Using TypeORM. "Human-readable" of exception says "Illegal argument to function". Query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  "Feedback"."id" AS "Feedback_id", 
  "Feedback"."created_at" AS "Feedback_created_at", 
  "Feedback"."updated_at" AS "Feedback_updated_at", 
  "Feedback"."lang_pair" AS "Feedback_lang_pair", 
  "Feedback"."target" AS "Feedback_target", 
  "Feedback"."source" AS "Feedback_source", 
  "Feedback"."translation_rating" AS "Feedback_translation_rating", 
  "Feedback"."external_id" AS "Feedback_external_id", 
  "Feedback"."client_id" AS "Feedback_client_id", 
  "Feedback"."updated_translation_rating" AS "Feedback_updated_translation_rating", 
  "Feedback"."status" AS "Feedback_status", 
  "Feedback"."feedback_source" AS "Feedback_feedback_source", 
  "Feedback"."third_party_id" AS "Feedback_third_party_id", 
  "Feedback"."license_id" AS "Feedback_license_id", 
  "Feedback_computed"."comment" AS "Feedback_computed_comment", 
  "Feedback_computed"."source_text" AS "Feedback_computed_source_text", 
  "Feedback_computed"."target_text" AS "Feedback_computed_target_text", 
  "Feedback_computed"."suggested_translation" AS "Feedback_computed_suggested_translation", 
  "Feedback_computed"."latest_translation" AS "Feedback_computed_latest_translation", 
  "Feedback_computed"."id" AS "Feedback_computed_id" 
FROM 
  "feedback" "Feedback" 
  LEFT JOIN "feedback_computed" "Feedback_computed" ON "Feedback_computed"."id" = "Feedback"."id"
```

`Feedback_computed` is the view that calls `pgp_sym_decrypt()`.

What might cause this issue? Or can you please help me debug it? How do I get more information about what's wrong?

Edit: FeedbackComputed view definition:

```sql
create view feedback_computed (id, comment, source_text, target_text, suggested_translation, latest_translation) as
SELECT feedback.id,
       pgp_sym_decrypt(feedback.comment_encrypted, '<encryption_key>'::text,
                       '<encryption_options>'::text)                                                                    AS comment,
       pgp_sym_decrypt(feedback.source_text_encrypted, '<encryption_key>'::text,
                       '<encryption_options>'::text)                                                                    AS source_text,
       pgp_sym_decrypt(feedback.target_text_encrypted, '<encryption_key>'::text,
                       '<encryption_options>'::text)                                                                    AS target_text,
       pgp_sym_decrypt(feedback.suggested_translation_encrypted, '<encryption_key>'::text,
                       'cipher-algo=aes256'::text)                                                                    AS suggested_translation,
       pgp_sym_decrypt(feedback.latest_translation_encrypted, '<encryption_key>'::text,
                       '<encryption_o>'::text)                                                                    AS latest_translation
FROM feedback feedback;

alter table feedback_computed
    owner to feedback;
```

Comment: Also show us the Feedback_computed definition.

Comment: Simplify as much as possible. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: @jarlh added view definition

Comment: What happens if you select directly from the view?

Comment: @jarlh same error

Comment: This issue only happens on the stage environment. Locally everything works.

Comment: If you have the same error when you select directly, you can simplify your question... divide and conquer...

Comment: yeah I guess the problem might be that I added this view recently and... Some of the view entities don't have a Feedback entry attached (is that how it works?) and so provide empty/null values to pgp_sym_decrypt() function, which is why it throws this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my issue was that it turns out that stage environment migrations that added the view weren't provided with encryption password (second argument to pgp_sym_decrypt), which meant that view got compiled with null value as password, which is why it gives "Illegal argumen to function".

Would've been much easier to fix if pgcrypto didn't give such *cryptic* error messages.